# swift: view is not in the view hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having a homeView which is the initial view to appear when app launches. In its **viewWillAppear()** method I check if the user is logged in. If not, he's redirected to login page and if he's not yet registered he'll be directed to sign-up page. I get an error when user clicks the sign-up button. The signUPView appears but it gives a warning that **Attempt to present loginViewController on signupViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy**. I have show detail segues between sign-up and login views. 
I'm performing the segue after uialert is presented.
I got solutions to put the code in viewDidAppear or ViewWillAppear method but I'm presenting the viewControllers upon button press. So I can't use these methods.

I have searched for a lot of solutions but unable to get the right one.
Please help!
Thank you.

segue triggering code from sign-up :

```
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        if self.registerSuccess == true {


                            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Registered!", message: "You have registered successfully!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

                                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                                self.nameTextField.text = ""
                                self.emailTextField.text = ""
                                self.passwordTextField.text = ""
                                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSegue", sender: self)
                            }))

                            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                        } else {
                            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Registration Failed!", message: "Please try again", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

                                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

                            }))

                            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                        }
```

[screenshot of my storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVNO3.png)

Comment: Maybe you could post your segue-triggering code? I find it hard to solve this from what you supplied :)

Comment: Edited my question. Also I have a direct storyBoard segue from login page to signUpViewController when user clicks sign-up button.

Comment: You do not have to call Dismiss for Alert View, it will be dismissed automatically when your action is getting called

Comment: Wait, why are you using `Show Detail` and not `Show`? I'm not very familiar with show detail.

Comment: ok I'll try changing the segue if it works!

Comment: It doesn't make any difference. I'm still getting the same error. It is because i'm triggering the segue from uiAlertView. But i need to do it that way